# really check if password has been changed

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, passwords, xen

On a non-critical server (Debian 7, kernel 3.2.65 x86_64) running under a Xen VM framework, it's a system I log on once a month under "user1".

Today I:
- cannot log as user1 via ssh+password
- can log as user1 via ssh+key auth
- cannot log as root via ssh+key auth (ssh root login forbidden)
- /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow haven't been changed from months (source: ls)
- chage -l user1 also give a last changed date for password months ago
- cannot su to root (password rejected)
- can su to user2 (password accepted), from there cannot su to user1 (password rejected). just exiting back to user1 is allowed (no pwd prompt needed)

my question: is there another way to:
- check if passwords have been changed ?
- understand what happens without root rights...

Also note that a major Xen upgrade on hostserver company has taken place on 22OCT (but I'm not sure it is significant on my issue)

Comment: I would place money on your troubles being connected to that upgrade.  Have you contacted the company if this behavior was expected?  A good hosting provider, which knows what they are doing, should be able to tell you if this was expected behavior or not.

Comment: OK, thanks for that insight. I did and waiting for their response. In the meantime I stop investigating following your view.

Comment: I guess you can't sudo on user1, it would be handy to check /etc/shadow and see when passords were last changed using 3rd field (day number since epoch)

Comment: no, can't sudo neither. but chage gives this information for user1 and it was months ago. so it doesn't explain why user1's password not working any more.

Comment: i detached/attach the system drive to another server to edit /etc/shadow and managed to log in again. the hosting company sees 3 possibles reasons : filesystem corruption, intrusion or bug in the VM script during reboot (an old version of this script used to change root password to the initial one, not last used). 1- fs clean 2- no trace but can be hidden 3- why user1 password would have been changed and not user2 ? (also true for intrusion option)